# Unit testing $scope.$on - event not caught

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a controller with a simple $scope.$on:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on("myBroadRcvr", function(event, data) {
        $scope.name = data.name;
        $scope.empID = data.empID;
    });
});
```

I have tried unit testing like this:

```
describe('MyController', function () {
    var $scope, super_controller;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller){
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            spyOn($scope, '$on');

            super_controller = $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});            
        });
    });

    it('should receive name as test', function (){

        var myData = {name: 'test', empID: 'eg7gg'},
        var sub_scope = $scope.$new();

        sub_scope.$broadcast('myBroadRcvr', myData);

        expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect($scope.name).toBe('test');
    });
});
```

With the above i get:

```
Expected undefined to be 'test'.
```

Comment: `expect($scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();` should also fail, isn't it.

Comment: @Pavlo - it doesnt seem to be failing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sub_scope` is the child of `$scope`, but `$broadcast` sends the event *downwards* the scope hierarchy, so your listener on the parent scope (`$scope` in this case) can't catch it. You should use `$emit` instead, as such:

```
sub_scope.$emit('myBroadRcvr', myData);
```

See the [docs on $broadcast here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast):

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

(contrast that with [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit), sending upwards.)

---

Your code also has a small syntax error: the line `var myData = {name: 'test', empID: 'eg7gg'},` should end with a `;` instead.

Comment: this is useful.. However i have still getting the same error. in my controller, $scope.name = data.name... so in my test, should it be $scope.myData.name?

Comment: no, it should be `$scope.name`. You also have a slight syntax error, the line assigning `myData` should end with a `;` instead of `,`. The basic principle works for me in a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/405p39HoSe58CJJHT9Ej?p=preview), can you post one recreating the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: so a slight improvement, i needed to spyOn($scope, '$emit'); in my inject and expect($scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("myBroadRcvr", {name: 'test', empID: 'eg7gg'}); seems to pass, but expect($scope.name).toBe('test'); fails

Comment: Asserting `expect($scope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalled...` will only tell you that you called `$emit` in your test - it's useless. Anyway, I suggest you remove the spy for now - If you replace emit with a spy, the actual `$emit` will not happen, unless you call `andCallThrough` on the spy. Please try to recreate your problem in a plunkr or any other [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it is becoming increasingly difficult to help without seeing your setup.

Comment: @OamPsy I forked your plunkr: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sq7J7jKNOlfalurA7cgB?p=preview), I added the original expectation, and it passes the test - I'm not sure, what's the issue. (I uncommented the spy parts, they are unnecessary, you can add them, but then you need to add `andCallThrough()` too so your actual handler runs. (I added that part too in a comment)